# Not finding location on LG Optimus U

Tags: gps, google-maps

Hey everyone. I'm a complete Android newb but computer poweruser, so I found this site based on experience with StackOverflow, ServerFault, etc. Go easy on me please. :)

I just got an LG Optimus U with US Cellular. In the pull-down menu I have GPS enabled (the satellite-looking thing with the beams), but when I open Google Maps and click the compass button, it says "Waiting for location" for a while and then says my location is temporarily unavailable.

Can anyone give me some recommendations on other things to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your settings in `Settings -> Location and security`. If you have a data plan, I'd suggest enabling `Use wireless networks`, `Use GPS satellites` and `Use sensor aiding` for the fastest possible location fix. If you don't want GPS to use your mobile data, deselect `Use wireless networks`.

Also, you could see what goes on with the GPS with GPS Test (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest).

Does the GPS icon start blinking in the notification bar when some program attempts to use the GPS?

Comment: Cool, I turned on use mobile network. It's blinking now, and working just fine to boot. Curious though, why it wouldn't get a fix even after 30 seconds?

Comment: The speed of the GPS fix depends on weather conditions, line of sight to the satellite, phone firmware, last GPS fix etc... My Galaxy S was a very problematic phone in the beginning, it could often take a couple minutes to get a fix. The answers on http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5768/475 have more info on GPS fixes and the ways the phone helps to make it faster.